# Solving an ODE dependent on a variable whose analytical expression is known with scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a differential equation dy/dt = f(t,y,k) where k is calculated by solving the differential equation dk/dx = g(t, y, k, x) (x and t are independent variables). Here's an example below where using the forward Euler method. For each time step, `k` is calculated by solving its differential equation `get_dkdx` using using its value in the previous loop.

```py
def forward_euler(f, t_eval, y0, k0):
    """ Forward Euler method
    :param f: function returning dy/dt 
    :param t_eval: time array
    :param y0: initial value of y
    :param k0: initial value of k """

    t = t_eval[0]
    y = y0
    k = k0
    x = np.linspace(0, 1)
    tsol, ysol, ksol = [t], [y], [k]

    for i in range(len(t_eval) - 1):

        # Calculate the time step
        dt = t_eval[i+1] - t_eval[i]

        # Calculate the new value of y, t and k
        k = scint.odeint(lambda k_, x_: get_dkdx(t, y, k_, x_), k[0], x).T[0]  # solve with respect to x taking the
                                                                               # previous value of k as initial value
        y += dt * f(t, y, k)
        t += dt

        # Store the new values
        tsol.append(t)
        ysol.append(y)
        ksol.append(k)

    return np.array(ysol), np.array(ksol)
```

Here's a simple example:

```py
def get_dydt(t, y, k):
    return np.sin(t) ** 2 * y - np.sum(k)  # random example


def get_dkdx(t, y, k, x):
    return k * x  # random example


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t1 = np.linspace(0, 5, 1001)
ysol1, ksol1 = forward_euler(get_dydt, t1, 2, np.linspace(0, 10))

figure, axes = plt.subplots(2)
axes[0].plot(t1, ysol1)
axes[1].plot(t1, ksol1)
axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[1].set_ylabel('k')
axes[0].set_xlabel('t')
axes[1].set_xlabel('t')
```

However, the Forward Euler method is not adequate for my problem and I have to use the Radau or RK45 methods from `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`. How can I do that?

Comment: I do not understand your `get_k` function. Is that intended to be a fixed-point equation, or some (implicit) integration? As it is, the value of `k` heavily depends on the step size, going to infinity as the step size goes to zero. As it is, there is nothing that can be put into a higher-order solver.

Comment: @LutzLehmann `get_k` is indeed supposed to be an integration in my case (but solved for a different variable than t). To be more precise about my problem, I have two differential equations: dy/dt = f(t, y, k) and dk/dx = g(t, y, k, x). Through each iterative step `i` in the Forward Euler method above, `k` is calculated by integrating over `x` (using any integration method), using its initial value at step `i-1`.

Comment: The integral value might depend on the path of `y`, making this situation nebulous. // You might need a derivative of `x` to get `dk/dt` per the chain rule, to add `k` (and `x`) as component of the ODE system.

Comment: My math background is not very impressive so please bear with me... Wouldn't solving dk/dt defeat the purpose of having an "analytical" expression for k? Just to precise, `x` and `t` are independent variables here. I have updated my question to reflect better my problem.

Comment: The ODE solver computes an (approximate) path in the state space. Apparently the state has the components `k,x,y`, in addition to the time `t`. Now `x` and `k` can be statically determined or dynamically. In the first case one has to solve implicit equations or treat the whole as a DAE system. In the second case you will need time derivatives of the other components from somewhere. // Another variant that fits your language is that you have a PDE system where `y` and `k` are functions of both `t` and `x` and the derivatives are of the partial nature.

Comment: I am indeed working on a PDE system. I thought it would be easier to explain my problem by simplifying it but it looks like I made it worse. Since the scope of my problem is more computational science orientated, I've posted the full problem [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/solving-a-pde-with-2-variables-with-one-variable-whose-derivative-with-respect) but I'll update this question if I ever manage to make it work.